# Pseudo-code questions on setting values to a large minus or large positive number

Tags: pseudocode

In a program where you input 10 positive numbers and output the smallest number input, if I created a variable called "Small", why do I need to set that to a large positive number. In other programs, i've seen it being set up as a large minus number. Why is this?

Comment: can you please elaborate a more? where do you need to set up large positive numbers? when are you creating small variable? and so fourth things.

Comment: I've just seen in the pseudocode for this program that when it starts, it sets up the variable to a large minus number. I am wondering why this is.

Comment: well, here at SO we don't psychic power to get to know the code you are troubled with.

Comment: (sigh) great community, I've asked 3 questions here and I'm new, I'm a student and just want some help, but seems to 'professional' for noobies like me. Guess I'm bad at explaining what I don't understand. Thanks, P. Hunter

Comment: I told you to tell us the problem in detail, show us the code you are talking about, where are the things you are not able to understand. *One can't find the answer without knowing the problem right?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you mean by calling your variable 'small' is that you're gonna compare it to each input value and use it to store the smallest value then return it.

But if the default value of your variable 'small' is already smaller than any input value then you will return a wrong result.

You can either set it to an arbitrary large number or use the first value in your input set to avoid the problem.